# XMPP Hosting Service

Tags: android, xmpp

I'm currently developing an Android app using XMPP as chat stack. I setup a local OpenFire server for the most part of my development, and am now considering using a commercial hosting service for production. There are a number of requirements I need to satisfy:

1. Needs to support client side user registration.
2. Needs to support IQProviders such as vCard (user profile) and query (user search).
3. Preferably no limit on number of users.

What are some of my options?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I should've mentioned I did do some research regarding this before posting the question, but nothing obvious came up. I emailed Dreamhost regarding their XMPP host service, and they don't support 1 and 2, only 3. Some other alternatives like venuecom or hosted.im appear to cap the number of users which doesn't satisfy my requirements. What are some of my other options?

Comment: Currently Flosoft.biz supports free XMPP hosting, running the latest Tigase. Tigase, unfortunately, does not support the search extension right now.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to come up with your own implementation of user registration, as OpenFire does not support it.
2. I don't know much here.
3. Now a single machine can hold up against 100k users. Now if you need to scale you are going to need to use Oracle Coherence, and it will work.

Point to note here: Coherence is not free, and it will cost $$. So if you chose OpenFire thinking it is free, you may want to check again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify, OpenFire does support in band registration. In fact, it supports everything I've listed, hence it's been used for internal testing. I do realize it comes at a cost at higher user count, that's why I posted the question.